# Invoke web service with T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to call a webservice through T-SQL on an `AFTER` trigger event. So far I return nothing but `NULL` values. Not sure where I am going wrong at this point and quite frankly don't understand what this fragment of code is actually doing. That would be a good place to start. I copied the code from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur) code project link, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TEST]
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @obj INT, 
    @response varchar(200),
    @sUrl varchar(200)

        set @sUrl = 'http://localhost:57961/Service1.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit&Fahrenheit=' + '100';

        EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, false
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
        EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response, OUT

        SELECT @response
        EXEC sp_OADestroy

END
```

Comment: Just my 2ct: There's the right tool for the job and there's the wrong tool for the job. Guess what my first thought was when I read the question title?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I'm hoping that it was a useful one, like 'What the right tool is'?

Comment: Don't do this - a trigger should be very **fast and nimble** - don't do any extensive processing, or lenghty web service calls, inside a trigger! This will kill your system performance .....

Comment: @marc_s Okay, I understand that this is not a great idea, but I am needing an application that triggers an event whenever a new record is INSERTed. Any suggestions on how to do this would be great.

Comment: The right tool would be to use a higher level language like C# (which is already in your tags) to call the web service and then update the database (if that is even what you want to do). From the code I see you try use a RDBMS to call a web service and return the data returned by that in a `SELECT` - that's plain sick if you have C# at hand to write the respective 4-liner which does it...

Comment: If you need to call a web service - I would have the trigger write a "note" into a separate table, and then have a separate C#/VB.NET service or console app somewhere that periodically checks that "command table" for entries. If there's anything in there - that app can then make the call and update data if needed - but the trigger itself shouldn't do such things.

Comment: You could use query notifications (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar There is no problem with calling the service in C#, hell I don't even need a service if I can do this another way. Like I said above I need an app that will recognize an SQL INSERT, grab the record and do operations.

Comment: @marc_s I guess he wants to avoid polling. Thus, when a new record is inserted, he wants to call a service to inform himself about the change.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Honestly, I don't know what I want to do. That's the problem. I had this project dumped on me and it's probably a bit over my head. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to make it happen.

Comment: @Volearix I wrote the comment about using C# before I read your comment about the notification idea. Look into query notifications, but beware of the fact that we've checked them out and found them pretty unreliable (we went back to polling). Do you *really* need to react *instantly* to the record being inserted or could a 2 second delay be ok? If a "few-second" delay is ok (which would also be the case with your web-service idea) polling works fine.

Comment: Also, that URL is wrong. You can't have two `?`. The second one should be `&`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I believe the delay might be acceptable, I have been on the outside looking in the whole time on this project. Terrible planning. I will check with them and see, but I know it's some kind of BOM application or something and they may want instantaneous results to the client.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Typo, fixed in the question.

Comment: @volearix Faster polling :-) You could also poll every second. That's as instantaneous as it gets. If you have a distributed application (client-server over network) delays will be normal anyway. Probably, network communication will be the limiting factor anyway.

Comment: Try `responseXml` instead of `responseText`.

Comment: While polling or some other solution is definitely a better answer here, if you really and truly have to do it this way, there is an extra comma between @response and OUT when you call sp_OAGetProperty.  Removing it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with all the statements above do not do this in a trigger. You can lock up the table badly.

However I did this a while ago using Service Broker and CLR functions. The idea is to place a event on the Service Broker queue and fire that off asynchronously to the receiver which called the CLR.

As Service broker is asynchronous the triggers always almost finish immediately and minimally affect the time to insert, update a row. There is some small caveats for example if the queue is poisoned you might want to insert the event into a queue table and then report a error. You can then resend those events once the queue is fixed.

As you are using a CLR you can leverage the power of .Net and web services extremely well which is a much better solution than trying to do some COM automation.

Recommend that you read the blog by [Remus Rusano](http://rusanu.com/articles/)  on high performance service broker queues. We managed to raise 81 million events in 24 hours on a development laptop however it took some serious elbow grease as this is not a 1,2,3 development effort.

Remus is also a very active member on the DBA stackexchange site so you can get more information there.